# How to access all items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

[RecyclerView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6WVl.png)

Hi 
RecyclerView read data from json
How to access all item value on click to order button and show items selected products on other activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
....
public ArrayList<MyItem> dataItems;

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        ....
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get position
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();

                // check if item still exists
                if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    MyItem clickedDataItem = dataItems.get(pos);
                    // here call your callback's method, or notify using other way
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but work for one item ,i want get all the items value on click on order button on activity @Andrew Scyter

Comment: I suppose, you should have the list of all items in activity. If loading data logic is in adapter itself, I think, you may add a callback with such data to activity, when loading completed

Comment: how to add callback ?  @Andrew Scyter

Comment: Add interface (MyAdapterCallback) and implement it in Activity. Then add param to adapter constructor (public MyAdapter (MyAdapterCallback callback) ) and then use it's methods.

Comment: Can you give me a sample? please .. @Andrew Scyter